# Using __thread in c99

Tags: c, multithreading, c99

I would like to define a few variables as thread-specific using the __thread storage class.  But three questions make me hesitate:

1. Is it really standard in c99?   Or more to the point, how good is the compiler support?
2. Will the variables be initialised in every thread?
3. Do non-multi threaded programs treat them as plain-old-globals?

Comment: just as an add-on to the received answers, thread local storage is planed for the upcoming standard C1x.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your specific questions:

1. No, it is not part of C99. You will not find it mentioned anywhere in the n1256.pdf (C99+TC1/2/3) or the original C99 standard.
2. Yes, `__thread` variables start out with their initialized value in every new thread.
3. From a standpoint of program behavior, thread-local storage class variables behave pretty much the same as plain globals in non-multi-threaded programs. However, they do incur a bit more runtime cost (memory and startup time), and there can be issues with limits on the size and number of thread-local variables. All this is rather complicated and varies depending on whether your program is static- or dynamic-linked and whether the variables reside in the main program or a shared library...

Outside of implementing C/POSIX (e.g. `errno`, etc.), thread-local storage class is actually not very useful, in my opinion. It's pretty much a crutch for avoiding cleanly passing around the necessary state in the form of a context pointer or similar. You might think it could be useful for getting around broken interfaces like `qsort` that don't take a context pointer, but unfortunately there is no guarantee that `qsort` will call the comparison function in the same thread that called `qsort`. It might break the job down and run it in multiple threads. Same goes for most other interfaces where this sort of workaround would be possible.

Comment: Of course thread-local data is always a bit of a hack, but that doesn't mean you don't sometimes need to hack.

Comment: Just want to mention gnulib here. It has a thread-local-store (tls) module, that takes care for most platforms/compilers. Consider it if you are writing (L)GPL software. I wouldn't start to write platform-independent code without it - saves your lifetime and reduces headaches.

Comment: Um, gnulib does not help you write platform-independent software. It helps you write software that has hard-coded platform-dependent hacks for some *N* wacky legacy platforms, and nothing else. Most of these hacks are not thread-safe and have all sorts of problematic corner-case bugs, too.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to read this:

http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf

1) MSVC doesn't support C99.  GCC does and other compilers attempt GCC compatibility.

**edit** A breakdown of compiler support for `__thread` is available here:

http://chtekk.longitekk.com/index.php?/archives/2011/02/C8.html

2) Only C++ supports an initializer and it must be constant.

3) Non-multi-threaded applications are single-threaded applications.

Comment: So, for (1), the answer is 'No; it is not in the C99 standard'.

Comment: It's listed as a storage class specifier in the C99 edits http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/C99-Thread_002dLocal-Edits.html

Comment: @Steve-o: That does not mean it has anything to do with C99. Rather, that document is just showing how C99 would be modified to include the `__thread` keyword. The upcoming C1x is expected to include thread-local storage class, but it's definitely not part of C99.